# Conditional expected value of throwing a die twice

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

> We throw a fair die twice. Let $X$ be equal to the result of the first throw and $Y$ be the non-negative difference of the throws. Calculate $E(X\mid Y)$ and $E(Y^2\mid X)$.

I want to ensure my reasoning and calculations are correct.

$X$ can take on values $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$, whereas $Y$: $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. Therefore the table of probabilities for those two random variables would look something like this:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\downarrow Y\backslash X \rightarrow  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & P(Y=j)\\ \hline
0 & \frac{1}{36}  & \frac{1}{36}  & \frac{1}{36}  &  \frac{1}{36} &  \frac{1}{36} &  \frac{1}{36} & \frac{6}{36}\\ \hline
1 & \frac{1}{36}  &  \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36}  & \frac{2}{36}  & \frac{2}{36}  & \frac{1}{36}  & \frac{10}{36}\\ \hline
2 & \frac{1}{36}  &  \frac{1}{36} &  \frac{2}{36} & \frac{2}{36}  & \frac{1}{36}  &  \frac{1}{36} & \frac{8}{36}\\ \hline
3 & \frac{1}{36}  & \frac{1}{36}  &  \frac{1}{36} & \frac{1}{36}  & \frac{1}{36}  & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{6}{36} \\ \hline
4 & \frac{1}{36}  &  \frac{1}{36} & 0  & 0  & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{1}{36}  & \frac{4}{36}  \\ \hline
5 & \frac{1}{36}  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  &  \frac{1}{36} & \frac{2}{36}\\ \hline
P(X=i) & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

(So e.g. $P(X=3 \cap Y=2) = \frac{2}{36}$).

Since both $X$ and $Y$ are discrete variables, both expected values would be: $E(X\mid Y)(\omega)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^6 i \cdot P(X=i\mid Y=j)$ and $E(Y^2\mid X)(\omega) =\sum\limits_{j=0}^5 j^2 \cdot P(Y=j\mid X=i)$.

I will give an example of how I calculated each of them:

$$P(X=k\mid Y=1)=\frac{P(X=k \cap Y =1)}{P(Y=1)}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\frac{1}{36}}{\frac{10}{36}} = \frac{1}{10}, & k\in \{1,6\} \\ 
\frac{\frac{2}{36}}{\frac{10}{36}} = \frac{2}{10}, & k\in \{2,3,4,5\}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Thus $E(X\mid Y=1)=\frac{1}{10}(1+6) + \frac{2}{10}(2+3+4+5) = \frac{35}{10}$ and:

$$E(X\mid Y)(\omega)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{7}{2}, & \omega \in \{Y=0 \}\\ 
\frac{7}{2}, & \omega \in \{Y=1 \}\\ 
\frac{7}{2}, & \omega \in \{Y=2\} \\ 
\frac{7}{2}, & \omega \in \{Y=3\}\\ 
\frac{7}{2}, & \omega \in \{Y=4\}\\ 
\frac{7}{2}, & \omega \in \{Y=5\}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Similarly, for the second conditional expected value we have:

$$P(Y=k\mid X=1) = \frac{P(Y=k \cap X=1)}{P(X=1)} = \frac{\frac{1}{36}}{\frac{1}{6}}=\frac{1}{6}$$

$E(Y^2\mid X=1) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{5}k^2 P(Y=k\mid X=1) = (0+1+4+9+16+25) \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{55}{6}$

Finally:

$$E(Y^2\mid X)(\omega) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{55}{6}, & \omega \in \{ X= 1 \} \\ 
\frac{31}{6}, &\omega \in \{ X= 2 \} \\ 
\frac{19}{6}, &\omega \in \{ X= 3 \} \\ 
\frac{19}{6}, &\omega \in \{ X= 4 \} \\ 
\frac{31}{6}, & \omega \in \{ X= 5 \} \\ 
\frac{55}{6}, & \omega \in \{ X= 6 \}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

However, as you can see, some of the final results for both of them are symmetrical. Although I can see why this is the case for $E(Y^2\mid X)$, I don't understand why it happened in $E(X\mid Y)$ and I had to calculate each value separately. Is there any way to see this more quickly?

Comment: The probabilities in the table are not correct, please check the numbers again.

Comment: @jvdhooft I've corrected two values, is it okay right now?

Comment: @Angie No, you calculated $E(X|Y=1)=\frac{35}{10}=\frac72$, but in $E(X|Y)(\omega)$, $\omega\in\{Y=1\}$ you wrote $\frac75$ instead. The same for $E(X|Y)(\omega)$, $\omega\in\{Y=4\}$. You can see by observing any raw in the joint distribution table that the distribution of $X$ given any value of $Y$ is symmetric w.r.t. $3.5$.

Comment: @NCh Oh, right. Sorry, I made a silly mistake with rewriting fractions while creating this post. Now I see that it is the same regardless of the value of $Y$, although I still don't know how to "see" it without the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1,X_2$ be the results of the two trials.

The following table gives the nonnegative differences $Y:$
$$
\begin{array}{|c|cccccc|}
\hline
\downarrow X_2\backslash X_1 \rightarrow  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Suppose we want the probability distribution of $X_1$ given that $Y=4.$ Then we're looking at this:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|cccccc|}
\hline
\downarrow X_2\backslash X_1 \rightarrow  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
1 &   &   &   &   & 4 &   \\
2 &   &   &   &   &   & 4 \\
3 &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
4 &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
5 & 4 &   &   &   &   &   \\
6 &   & 4 &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
We have $X_1=1,2,5,6$ with equal probabilities, and that distribution is symmetric about the average, which is $7/2.$

But now suppose we want the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given that $Y=2.$ Then we're looking at this:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|cccccc|}
\hline
\downarrow X_2\backslash X_1 \rightarrow  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
1 &   &   & 2 &   &   &   \\
2 &   &   &   & 2 &   &   \\
3 & 2 &   &   &   & 2 &   \\
4 &   & 2 &   &   &   & 2 \\
5 &   &   & 2 &   &   &   \\
6 &   &   &   & 2 &   &   \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Then we have
$$
X_1 = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{with probability } p, \\
2 & \text{with probability } p, \\[4pt]
3 & \text{with probability } 2p, \\
4 & \text{with probability } 2p, \\[4pt]
5 & \text{with probability } p, \\
6 & \text{with probability } p,
\end{cases}
$$
so $p+p+2p+2p+p+p = 1,$ and thus $p=1/8,$ so $X_1=1,2,5,\text{ or }6$ each with probability $1/8$ and $X_1=3\text{ or }4$ each with probability $1/4.$

This is still symmetric about the average of all six numbers, which is still $7/2.$

And similarly with the other numbers.